# Can't use custom class in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a custom service in my project. I create a class, Ex: `Services/Auth.js` with following content.

```
class Auth {
    isLoggedIn() {
        return true;
    }
}

export default Auth;
```

Then in my component I import and use as under:

```
import Auth from './Services/Auth';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        // ... so on ...
    }
}
```

It compiles, but on rutime, it throws following error:

```
TypeError: _Services_Auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default.isLoggedIn is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting the class itself, not an instance of it.

You'll want something like

```
class Auth {
    isLoggedIn() {
        return true;
    }
}

export default new Auth();
```

to export a singleton instance.

Comment: What's the science behind exporting component classes without instantiating?